# R get the next n words after matching string

Tags: r, regex, string

If this is my string.

```
"Mrs Miller IDN: 29.23 FT/GHI. 35.3 degree C wants the entire house repainted."
```

How can I capture the text, `29.23` which appears after `IDN:` and ignore the rest.

I have tried a lot of gsub functions and the results are not very good.

Comment: You say you tried something, please share to see where it went wrong.

Comment: `strtrim(gsub("([0-9]+.[0-9]+)|\\C", "\\1", str, perl = TRUE), 5)`

Comment: `library(stringi); unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(unlist(strsplit("Mrs Miller IDN: 29.23 FT/GHI. 35.3 degree C wants the entire house repainted.", "IDN:"))[2],"[0-9\\.]+"))[1]`

Comment: Nice alternative to the other two answers...i'll submit as a community wiki for you.

Answer (score 2):

You never told us what you tried and where it went wrong, yet other than this your question is well-stated.  My guess is that you were using the wrong pattern in your call to `gsub()`.

```
str <- "Mrs Miller IDN: 29.23 FT/GHI. 35.3 degree C wants the entire house repainted."
gsub(".*IDN: ([^[:space:]]*?)\\s.*", "\\1", str)
[1] "29.23"
```

Comment: I wonder if you know what `[^\\s]*?` matches here. Edit: And yes, `[^[:space:]]*?` is correct. But you could use a greedy quantifier at least to make it work smoother.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It matches _not_ literal backslash or the letter s, clearly not what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sub()` and `strplit`...

```
string <- "Mrs Miller IDN: 29.23 FT/GHI. 35.3 degree C wants the entire house repainted."

string <- sub(" .*", "", sapply(strsplit(string, "IDN: "), "[", 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

d.b. answer...

However, I'm not sure it makes sense to load an additional package when two base solutions are provided.

```
library(stringi); unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(unlist(strsplit("Mrs Miller IDN: 29.23 FT/GHI. 35.3 degree C wants the entire house repainted.", "IDN:"))[2],"[0-9\\.]+"))[1]
```

snoram answer with `perl`

```
strtrim(gsub("([0-9]+.[0-9]+)|\\C", "\\1", str, perl = TRUE), 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The always fun `word` function of `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

word(word(x, 2, sep = 'IDN: '), 1)
#[1] "29.23"
```